# How do I make a SQL Server and connect mysql Shell to it

Tags: sql

I've seen people ask the same question but they already have the local server ready, but I don't know how to make one, so can someone help me and show me how to make a SQL Server

Comment: Mysql and sql server are two different database systems

Comment: Do you mean **SQL Server** (as in Microsoft's RDBMS product), or did you mean a **MySQL server** ? Those are **not** the same - but both, you don't *make* - you install....

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to install MySQL Server, here are the instructions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing.html

Instructions for connecting MySQL Shell (8.0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-using-parameters.html

However, I'm assuming you are asking for instructions for installing Microsoft SQL Server 2019  ("SQL Server" is usually inferred to mean Microsoft's database).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

If you are intending to work with Microsoft SQL Server, you may find Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition to be an easier tool:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-connections?view=vs-2019

SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/

You may also be interested in looking at the free database tools offered by EMS (which supports working with MySQL, PostrgreSQL, ..., and SQL Server)
https://www.sqlmanager.net/en/tools/free

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows?
You need to install the server, because you mention mysql, download it here
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

After you have installed it you can download a mysql client to manage your server, like mysql workbench

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Maybe you use linux because you mentioned shell?

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Configure the server

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation utility
```

Start the service

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Start the mysql shell

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
```